# Property 'over' does not exist on type 'typeof @stomp/stompjs/index'

Tags: angular, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am trying to create a chat app using spring websocket and using angular as the frontend. I am importing Stomp and SockJS:

```
import SockJS from "sockjs-client"
import * as Stomp from "@stomp/stompjs"
```

And then using it as:

```
let socket = new SockJS('/ws');
this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
```

But I'm getting this error at Stomp.over() and I'm not sure why. Has it been deprecated or do I need to install a module?

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue solved by this.

Instead of importing
`import * as Stomp from "@stomp/stompjs"`

import {Stomp} alone

```
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import {Stomp} from '@stomp/stompjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

npm install stompjs
import Stomp from "stompjs"

This solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

[Dharun's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13798280/dharun)  answer work's great for me

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67773348/16097417).
change importing style to

```
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import {Stomp} from '@stomp/stompjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

`@stomp/stompjs`is a new version, you should do this:

```
const client = new Client({
          brokerURL: '',//can blank，because use SockJS
          connectHeaders: {"Authorization":xxx},
          debug: function (str) {
            console.log(str)
          },
          reconnectDelay: 5000,
          heartbeatIncoming: 4000,
          heartbeatOutgoing: 4000,
        });
        client.webSocketFactory = function () {
          return new SockJS('/ws');
        };
```

the doc : [Using STOMP with SockJS](https://stomp-js.github.io/guide/stompjs/rx-stomp/ng2-stompjs/using-stomp-with-sockjs.html)